# Populating a JavaScript Array where elements in one array need to partially match another, and then be combined

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have two arrays, one which contains option codes and another which contains their descriptions. What is the most efficient way of creating an array that contains both the code and it's definition?

the first array looks like this and contains the code

`[ '1CA', '1CD', '205', '258', '2K1', '2VH', '302', '322', '386', '3AG', '417', '423', '428', '430', '431', '441', '459', '494', '4BN', '4UR', '4UY', '502', '508', '522', '524', '534', '571', '601', '609', '644', '676', '698', '6VC', '812', '823', '845', '853', '876', '8KA', '8S1', '8S3', '8TM', '925', '992', '9AA' ]`

and the second array looks like this and contains the code (although with an S and A either side) and it's definition.

```
['S000A Dummy-SALAPA\n',
    'S001A Nat.vers. not controlled as package\n',
    'S0BVA Refueling until tank full\n',
    'S0BWA Partial fueling\n',
    'S100A Usable load increase\n',
    'S102A Chassis, officials utility vehicle\n',
    'S102A Reinforced brakes\n',
    'S103A Four seasons tyres\n',
    'S103A Aggregate protective plate\n',
    'S115A Paramedic sticker NRW\n',
    'S115A NRW Fire-brigade Sticker\n',
    'S4BNA Fine-wood trim ash grain\n',
    'S117A Banner staff, right\n',
    'S160A Installation, Becker Signal Syst.LU 322\n',
    'S161A Emissions standard EU5\n']
```

Comment: The code and the definition in the same combined string? The code and definition matched together as an array of arrays? The code and definition as an array of objects? As an object? Be clear about the exact end-result you want to achieve. How far did you get when you tried to solve the problem? What went wrong? Where's the code of your best attempt? We know nothing about your code, or your intentions except what you tell us, and if we can't tell what you want we cannot help you.

Comment: Hi. Apologies I should have been more clear about the output I am looking for. I would like to end up with an array of objects that contain both the code and the definition. So something like `let finalArray = [ {code: '4BN', definition: 'Fine-wood trim ash grain'}]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the only code that has a corresponding definition is `4BN`:

```js
const codes = [
  '1CA', '1CD', '205', '258', '2K1', '2VH', '302', '322',
  '386', '3AG', '417', '423', '428', '430', '431', '441',
  '459', '494', '4BN', '4UR', '4UY', '502', '508', '522',
  '524', '534', '571', '601', '609', '644', '676', '698',
  '6VC', '812', '823', '845', '853', '876', '8KA', '8S1',
  '8S3', '8TM', '925', '992', '9AA',
];

const definitions = [
  'S000A Dummy-SALAPA\n',
  'S001A Nat.vers. not controlled as package\n',
  'S0BVA Refueling until tank full\n',
  'S0BWA Partial fueling\n',
  'S100A Usable load increase\n',
  'S102A Chassis, officials utility vehicle\n',
  'S102A Reinforced brakes\n',
  'S103A Four seasons tyres\n',
  'S103A Aggregate protective plate\n',
  'S115A Paramedic sticker NRW\n',
  'S115A NRW Fire-brigade Sticker\n',
  'S4BNA Fine-wood trim ash grain\n',
  'S117A Banner staff, right\n',
  'S160A Installation, Becker Signal Syst.LU 322\n',
  'S161A Emissions standard EU5\n',
];

const definitionsMap = new Map(definitions.map(s => {
  const [code, ...definition] = s.split(' ');
  return [code.substring(1, 4), definition.join(' ').trimEnd()];
}));

const codesWithDefinitions = codes.map(c => ({code: c, definition: definitionsMap.get(c)}))
                                  .filter(c => c.definition);
console.log(codesWithDefinitions);
```